# Android open SQLite Database in Fragment

Tags: java, android, sql, database, fragment

I am in a fragment in Android Studio java and want to save and read something there in a SqLite database. To save, I just use this code:

```
databaseHu = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase(databaseName_Notes, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
databaseHu.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Tabel_Hu_Name + "(subject TEXT, tasks TEXT, dayofyear INT, day INT, month INT, year INT)");
databaseHu.execSQL("INSERT INTO  " + Tabel_Hu_Name + " VALUES ('" + subject.getText().toString() + "','" + tasks.getText().toString() + "','" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + "','" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "','" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "','" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "')");
databaseHu.close();
```

But because I'm in a fragment, it marks that:

```
getBaseContext()
```

as a mistake.
How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use to use sqlite open helper in android to deal with sqlite but can you try getActivty() instead of getBaseContext()??

Comment: I tried getActivity (). That does not work, the app then crashes there.

Comment: `"( subject` add space here

Comment: I tried that. But the app closes by the first line. -> openOrCreateDatabas....

Comment: can you post the error logcat?

Answer (score 1):

You can use getActivity() like this,

```
databaseHu = getActivity().getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase(databaseName_Notes, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

but it may invoke nullPtrException. Instead you can override this function and create like this:

```
Activity activity;
@override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(getActivity()==null){
        activity = getActivity;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this,

```
databaseHu = activity.getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase(databaseName_Notes, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Comment: Should I write activity = getActivity(); ? Because else it makes an error on =getActivity;